# How to ensure that the "bind" order is not skipped in tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create a game using tkinter in which the players enter their names into an entry widget.

After entering their name, the user should press enter to call the function "player_names", which would ideally save the players name in a list, delete the text in the entry widget and then continue to the next loop (i.e player).

The script seems to be ignoring the bind and and moving straight to the line "self.name_entry.destroy()". How do I ensure that the script waits for the  command before continuing?

```
def initialise_game(self, num_of_players):

    self.players_list = []
    for i in range(num_of_players):
        player_num = i+1
        self.name_label = tk.Label(self.bg_label, text='What is the name'
                                   ' of Player ' + str(player_num) + '?')
        self.name_label.grid(row=0, padx=200, pady=120)

        self.name_entry = tk.Entry(self.bg_label)
        self.name_entry.grid(row=1, padx=200, pady=0)
        self.name_entry.bind('<Return>', self.player_names)

    self.name_entry.destroy()


def player_names(self, event):
    self.players_list.append(self.name_entry.get())
    self.name_entry.delete(0, 'end')
```

Comment: It seems like you want to delete every entry after entering the value to them, is this what you trying?

Comment: It seems you don't uderstand how GUI works. `Entry` and `bind` don't work like `input()`. They don't wait for your text. They only inform mainloop what widget it has to display and what mainloop has to do when you will press `Enter`. They don't stop code so everything after Entry, bind is executed at once - and it is even executed  before you see window because `mainloop` starts everything. If you want to destroy widget after you press Eneter then you have to do it in `player_names` which is executed when you press Enter.

Comment: your loop creates many `Entry` at once but it puts all entries in the same cell so you don't see it. Use `grid(row=i,...)` and you will see many `Entry` in window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Entry` doesn't work like `input()` it will not stop code and wait till you put text and press enter. `GUI` creates `Entry` and it executes code after `Entry` at once. You have `bind` to assign function which will be executed whey you press Enter and this function should get value from Entry, and replace widgets (or only text in Label). It also should remove `Entry` after last player so you have to count how many times function was executed (or how many players you already have - `self.player_num`)

I didn't test this code but it should works.

```
def initialise_game(self, num_of_players):

    self.players_list = []

    # remeber values in class variables, not local one
    self.num_of_players = num_of_players
    self.player_num = 0

    # create only one Label - and change text in it
    self.name_label = tk.Label(self.bg_label,
    self.name_label.grid(row=0, padx=200, pady=120)

    # create only one Entry and assign function `self.player_names`
    self.name_entry = tk.Entry(self.bg_label)
    self.name_entry.grid(row=1, padx=200, pady=0)
    self.name_entry.bind('<Return>', self.player_names)

    # set text for first player
    self.player_num += 1
    self.name_label["text"] = 'What is the name of Player {} ?'.format(player_num)

def player_names(self, event):

    # get player's name from Entry                                    
    self.players_list.append(self.name_entry.get())
    self.name_entry.delete(0, 'end')

    # set text for next player or destroy Entry after last player
    self.player_num += 1
    if self.player_num <= self.num_of_players:
        self.name_label["text"] = 'What is the name of Player {} ?'.format(player_num)
    else:
        self.name_label.destroy()                               
        self.name_entry.destroy()
```

---

The same way it works in other GUIs (not only in `tkinter`) and other languages (not only in `Python`)

Answer (score 0):

My idea of what are you trying to acomplish shuld be the same, to take an input from the player one by one until all player have added a name.
The ploblem with your code is the `for`, it needs to complite without an input from the player (tecnicly), insted i opted for the update mecanics that tkinter have, wen a value changes in a winget the winget will update itself and i bind to the button a change value from a increment.
If you want to reuse `i` , reference it a the start of the `def` the same wey

This example works, the input of `initialise_game` is the same as before, replacing the conde in the middle will work just fine, except if your code uses `.grid()` then replace `ask_name.pack()`

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.bg_label = tk.Frame(root)

# Added code, top and bottom are for testing
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

root.players_list = []  # Global variabe witch can be accesd by all funcions

i = 1 # This global value is to keep a clear reference on the count of windows
def initialise_game(self, num_of_players): 
    ask_name = tk.Frame(self)
    L = tk.Label(ask_name, text=('What is the name of Player ' + str(i) + '?'))
    L.grid(row=0, padx=200, pady=120)
    E = tk.Entry(ask_name)
    def modify_entry(NULL):
        root.players_list.append(E.get())
        E.delete(0, 'end')
        global i # Change the "search" of values to outside the funtion
        i += 1
        L.config(text=('What is the name of Player ' + str(i) + '?'))
        if (i > num_of_players): # Close the Frame wen all were answered
            root.players_list.append(E.get())
            ask_name.destroy()
    E.bind('<Return>', modify_entry)
    E.grid(row=1, padx=200, pady=0)
    ask_name.pack() # You can replace it with grin , this moves the Label + Entry were u want

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

initialise_game(root.bg_label, 3)
root.bg_label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```